# How important is the experience of the radiologist to diagnose a tendinopathy when reading an MRI?

Tags: tendinopathy, mri, medical-imaging

I read on {1}:

> Preoperative ultrasound examination of the shoulder permits a reliable diagnosis of complete rotator cuff tears and calcium deposits (calcific tendinitis). **The method is less sensitive but sufficiently reliable for the diagnosis of partial rotator cuff tears and pathology of the long biceps tendon. Examiner experience plays an important role in these special cases.** Permanent continuous training in the field of ultrasound diagnosis is a prerequisite for sufficient reliability of ultrasound diagnosis of shoulder disorders.

Is there any scientific study/survey that tried to quantify the importance of the  experience of the radiologist to diagnose a tendinopathy when reading an MRI?

---

References:

- {1} Kayser, R., S. Hampf, M. Pankow, E. Seeber, and C. E. Heyde. "Validity of ultrasound examinations of disorders of the shoulder joint." Ultraschall in der Medizin (Stuttgart, Germany: 1980) 26, no. 4 (2005): 291-298. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16123923 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170521212710/https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16123923))

Comment: I've never seen anything, but if it exists it's unlikely to be available outside of the orthopedic or radiology journals

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this publication of Sein et al., '**Reliability of MRI assessment of supraspinatus tendinopathy**.' ([PMID 17289860](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2465433/))

[image]

Sein ML et al. *Reliability of MRI assessment of supraspinatus tendinopathy.* Br J Sports Med. 2007 Aug;41(8):e9. Epub 2007 Feb 8. https://dx.doi.org/10.1136%2Fbjsm.2006.034421